# Heroku deploy ends with error npm ERR! 404 Not Found: event-stream@3.3.6

Tags: node.js, json, heroku, npm

I am trying to deploy nodejs to heroku (or firebase) and I receive the same error which relates to event-stream@3.3.6 .
I read that it was dismissed but when updating to 4.0.1 I still get the same error. 
I tried to uninstall and re-install and to delete node-module path but with no success.
Any suggestions?

```
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 10.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.14.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.4.1
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        npm ERR! code E404
remote:        npm ERR! 404 Not Found: event-stream@3.3.6
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.i7KQx/_logs/2018-12- 
06T15_24_26_926Z- 
debug.log
```

my package.json:
[package.json](https://ufile.io/z57wi)

my package-lock.json:
[package-lock.json](https://ufile.io/basb3)

Comment: event-stream@3.3.6 was hacked and deleted from npm. Use 3.3.5 or 4.x version. run `npm audit fix` to solve the problem.

Comment: Tried that, 3.3.5 or 4.x and it didnt work. It insists to have 3.3.6

Comment: Fixed, thanks. I believe the problem was that heroku was locked on the same repository and my trials was for vain. I had to close / open cmd to reset.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have to delete the entire `node_modules` directory and was able to solve the very same issue following the appropriate steps beginning with simply doing a search in your code Editor (I use VS Code) and look for places where this particular version is mentioned in the entire project directory.

```
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        npm ERR! code E404
remote:        npm ERR! 404 Not Found: event-stream@3.3.6
```

Update all instances where you see the compromised referenced version with the most current one. At the time of this post, I updated to `4.0.1`. 
Save all changes and in the directory of your file, run

```
npm i event-stream --save and you should see a success
```

run `npm install` once changes are saved so that packages are updated, you should see something like this:

```
+ event-stream@4.0.1
updated 1 package and audited 2504 packages in 5.716s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

BUT WAIT, the error is still there??? Did you remember to commit your changes? I didn't initially. So got another error.

```
remote:        npm ERR! code E404
remote:        npm ERR! 404 Not Found: event-stream@3.3.6
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.i1VvE/_logs/2018-12-14T22_03_01_715Z- 
debug.log
```

Rookie Note regarding Github deployments -- If you are doing a `git push heroku master` to deploy your app, make sure to commit all your `package.json` and `package.lock.json` changes to the master branch of the project and merge the code, otherwise, Heroku won't pick up your changes as it always looks to mirror your master branch.
Novice mistake but easy to overlook when working with multiple branches.

Voila, the deployment worked

```
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        
remote:        > nodemon@1.18.6 postinstall 
/tmp/build_b1cf3a0085ddaf6796dc22cf8066c082/node_modules/nodemon
remote:        > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
```

You can now proceed to Heroku to verify the built and hopefully see your work deployed.

Comment: Wanted to add that you don't need to manually find and change the version of that dependency, `npm i event-stream --save` will do that for you. So, you do that first, then `npm install` and then `git push` command.

Answer (score 1):

event-stream 3.3.6 have vulnerability
https://blog.npmjs.org/post/180565383195/details-about-the-event-stream-incident

you must change event-stream latest version

```
$ npm i event-stream --save
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is simply clean install packages to upgrade to latest patches and this should be resolved:

```
1. npm uninstall

2. npm install npm-run-all nodemon
```

Also delete your `package-lock.json` file if you have it.

Make sure you commit all changes before deploying to heroku